# formatting string in python using format

Tags: python, string, format, md5sum

There is code:

```
xor = 127002634777471167503839844242873650079
print '{0:x}'.format(xor)
print format(xor, 'x')
```

Can anyone explain what two last strings means?
How 5f8bd156f9e50e5381ab282ba2000b9f is generated from xor variable?

Comment: It's hexa-decimal representation of 127002634777471167503839844242873650079. `127002634777471167503839844242873650079 == 0x5f8bd156f9e50e5381ab282ba2000b9f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this is the Hexa representation of your number.

You can set it to `.2f` (double in normal (fixed-point) notation), for example:

```
xor = 127002634777471167503839844242873650079
print '{0:.2f}'.format(xor)
print format(xor, '.2f')
```

Or using `.2g` (double in either normal or exponential notation, This type differs slightly from fixed-point notation in that insignificant zeroes to the right)

```
print '{0:.2g}'.format(xor)
```

You can read more about the type field (`.2f` and `.3g`) in 
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#fprintf)